# Why is this node.js app starting a new session on every page view in production, but not in my local environment?

Tags: node.js, express, session, dokku

I am making a website using node.js/express. The website works perfectly fine when I run it on my mac, but when I push it to my Digital Ocean Dokku droplet there is a problem with persisting sessions.

Whenever I navigate to a new page locally, the session persists; however, whenever I navigate to a new page in production, a new session is created - and then various other things on the site break as a result.

Initially I was managing sessions using connect-redis, but I have switched it out in favour of express-mysql-session to see if that made a difference (it didn't).

I can also see the new sessions being created in the redis store/database, and so to my mind that rules out the issue being the connection with the database.

I am setting up the sessions in my `app.js` file as follows:

```
  // 3. Set up and use sessions

  const sessionStore = new MySQLStore({}, db.pool)

  const sessionMiddleware = session({
    store: sessionStore,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 90,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'strict'
    }
  })

  app.use(sessionMiddleware)
```

Is there anything here which might explain what the problem is, or can anyone think of anything in my production environment I should be looking at to try and identify the source of the issue?

Many thanks

Comment: The next step is to see if the cookie getting back to the browser and then to see if the cookie is getting sent from the browser back to the site. You can do this using your browser's devtools. (For the first, you can use "Network" and initialise the session again to see if any Cookie headers are coming back from the server. For the second, "Application"->"Cookies" will let you see if any are set for the site you're accessing.)

Comment: Another thing to consider is you're creating a https-only cookie in production, so if you're accessing your site over plain old http for some reason at this early stage, it won't work. I would consider setting secure: false, httpOnly: false and ditching sameSite temporarily to see if helps (just in order to make the session cookie as unrestricted as possible.)

Comment: @PeterCooper thanks so much for this. I went through the steps you suggested and there's no set-cookie in the response or request headers, so I then set secure: false and it is now working correctly (albeit insecurely). To confirm, I am accessing the site over https